# PHP automatically removes the zeros that i need in an identification string

Tags: php, mysql

In a table, the primary field is a Char(12) field called `ribiid`, whose format is `RB##########`,

It needs to auto-increment it self, and for that i have prepared the following code:

```
function getid() {
   global $connection;
   $idquery = "SELECT ribiid FROM systems ORDER BY ribiid DESC LIMIT 1";
   $idsave = mysqli_query($connection, $idquery);
   $idresult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($idsave);
   $idalpha = substr($idresult['ribiid'], 0, 2);
   $idnumeric = substr($idresult, 2);
   $newidnumeric = $idnumeric + 1;
   $newid = $idalpha . $newidnumeric;
   return $newid;
}
```

Now for testing I manually entered a row in cmd with `id = RB0000000000`, the next entry that I submit through my webpage using php, should have been `RB0000000001`, but it is coming RB1.

How can I fix this, this is my first web database. Thanks

Comment: You should use MySQL's [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-auto-increment.html) feature, rather than attempting to implement something like this in PHP (which, if you're not *extremely* careful, will lead to race hazards).

Comment: Yeah, use auto increment, and then when you wish to use your format, use `sprintf` with a string prefix.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what are Race Hazards?

Comment: @user3324298, Race Hazzards are when you have multiple writes and you expect one to finish before the other and rely on incorrect data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$newid = $idalpha . str_pad($newidnumeric, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

This will add zeros to reach the ten chars.

Comment: Still subject to race hazards.

Comment: Sure, but that's not the question. He will have his reasons to do it this way.

Comment: I doubt that: "*this is my first web database*".

Comment: Worked perfectly. Tested it 11 times to try double digit increase, and worked as desired. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that when adding 1 to `$idnumeric` PHP needs to treat it as a number. Leading zeroes in numbers do not make sense, so they are discarded.

To keep the zeroes you can use `sprintf` format the resulting (incremented) number:

```
$newid = sprintf("%s%010d", $idalpha, $newidnumeric);
```

#### However, using code like this is not a really good idea

There's an issue with this code though: it's subject to a race condition. Consider what could happen if two instances of the script run in parallel:

```
                Instance A                    Instance B
T  |
i  |            Reads ribiid RB..001          Reads ribiid RB..001
m  |            Generates next id RB..002     Generates next id RB..002
e  v            Writes RB..002 to DB
                                              Writes RB..002 to DB => OOPS
```

As you see this situation will result in instance B failing to insert a record due to the use of a duplicate primary key. To solve this problem you need to eliminate the race condition, which you could do in one of several ways:

- Use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column for the PK instead of manually inserting values. Although this means you can no longer have the "RB" prefix as part of the key, you *can* move it to a different column and have the PK be a combination of these two columns.
- `LOCK TABLES ribiid` while the insertion is taking place (note that the lock needs to cover *all* of the process, not just the `getid` function). Locking tables is something you normally want to avoid, but if inserts are not frequent it's a usable practical solution.

Comment: @eggyal: Explaining that to the OP would be more constructive. In any case, still editing.

Comment: @eggyal: That's a warning, not an explanation.

Comment: Oh, i get it now. I should have submitted the complete code here. So this function only runs when a user completes a form and presses the submit button. So, its not generating a new id when the form loads.

Comment: @user3324298: That's not hard to guess. The race condition is rather theoretical here because human interaction with the form is so slow and infrequent in computer terms, but it *could* happen if two users submit the form "at the same time".

Comment: Plus, this database is designed for a local intranet site. Less than 100 users, I highly doubt that a situation where two users press the submit button together will arise.


Thanks a ton though. I'll try your code and if it works, vote it as the answer.

Comment: @user3324298: With so little traffic you 're not likely to ever hit it (and if you do, a user gets an error in the face -- which might not be that bad, they can simply retry). But you should be aware that this is not a "proper solution".

Comment: @user3324298: But why build something "the wrong way" just because you don't expect the failure ever to arise?  How serious would a failure be if it did arise?  Might it lead to irreparable corruption of data?  What happens when the business using this product is hugely successful and the number of users using it grows many-fold?  Or a decision is taken to monetise the product by making it available to others?  Surely it's better to build it right from the outset than have to battle a million fires further down the road?

Comment: @eggyal: Starbucks ask your name to use as a unique ID so you can retrieve the correct drink after the barista makes it. Now names are far from unique, but they still do it "the wrong way" because *building it right is never going to produce ROI* and because *the frequency and consequences of a failure are well within acceptable limits*. Programming is not done in ivory towers, that's why we call ourselves software *engineers*. You do have a point, but your analysis is hopelessly one-sided.

Comment: @eggyal: I did. *"Surely it's better to build it right from the outset than have to battle a million fires further down the road?"* is still hopelessly one-sided. Unless you can predict the future, of course. Also, didn't I say a million times that one should not exaggerate?

Comment: Sorry, but the code didn't work properly. The resultant id was       "RB   (9 spaces)      1" and not "RB0000000001". But the code from @trizz worked, so solved. In any case, i think i am gonna use the autoincrement feature and write code to represent it on the form in the required format. Thanks.

Comment: @user3324298: Duh. Now that you mention it, that `%10d` I wrote should have been `%010d` (extra zero). Silly mistake, glad you solved it in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You can padd the numeric string again using the following function:

```
function pad_number($number, $pad=10){
  $pad_zero = $pad - strlen($number.'');
  $nstr = '';
  for($i =0; $i< $pad_zero; $i++){
    $nstr .="0";
  }
  $nstr .= $number;
  return $nstr;
}
```

You can use in your code this function as:

```
$newid = $idalpha . pad_number($newidnumeric);
```

Comment: Please don't create your own functions for standard language functions.